# Android SQLite query optimization (ORM GreenDao)

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao

My job is to maintain an application that is essentially a database for another application. the application uses ORM GreenDao.
Here is StorageUtil.getResults method which processes queries:

```
public static JSONArray getResults(Database database, String query) {
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
        JSONArray resultSet = new JSONArray();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            int totalColumn = cursor.getColumnCount();
            JSONObject rowObject = new JSONObject();

            for (int i = 0; i < totalColumn; i++) {
                if (cursor.getColumnName(i) != null) {
                    try {
                        if (cursor.getString(i) != null) {
                            if (isJSONValid(cursor.getString(i))) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(cursor.getString(i));
                                    rowObject.put(cursor.getColumnName(i), object);
                                }catch (JSONException e){
                                    Logger.error(e);
                                }
                            } else {
                                rowObject.put(cursor.getColumnName(i), cursor.getString(i));
                            }
                        } else {
                            rowObject.put(cursor.getColumnName(i), "");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Logger.error(e);
                    }
                }
            }
            resultSet.put(rowObject);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return resultSet;
    }
```

Here is code of one of my entities:

```
@Entity(nameInDb = "UI_SV_FIAS")
@Storage(description = "FIAS", table = "UI_SV_FIAS")
public class Fias {
    @Id
    public String LINK;

    @Property(nameInDb = "F_Street")
    public String F_Street;

    @Property(nameInDb = "C_Full_Address")
    @Index
    public String C_Full_Address;

    @Property(nameInDb = "C_House_Number")
    public String C_House_Number;

    @Property(nameInDb = "C_Building_Number")
    public String C_Building_Number;

    public Fias() {
    }

    @Generated(hash = 1534843169)
    public Fias(String LINK, String F_Street, String C_Full_Address,
            String C_House_Number, String C_Building_Number) {
        this.LINK = LINK;
        this.F_Street = F_Street;
        this.C_Full_Address = C_Full_Address;
        this.C_House_Number = C_House_Number;
        this.C_Building_Number = C_Building_Number;
    }
```

Problem: the table has about 2,500,000 rows and when I get a query, for example, like this one:

```
 http://localhost:8888/table?name=UI_SV_FIAS&query=select * from UI_SV_FIAS where C_Full_Address LIKE '%Чеченская%' ORDER BY C_House_Number, C_Full_Address limit 10
```

my app returns results in more then 10 seconds. But what I need is less then 3 seconds for such query.
Does anyone have an idea how can I get that?

Comment: Can you reduce your code to the actual problem, so we can see the actual query without the need to decypher all your unrelated code parts?

Comment: So%20now%20we%20only%20need%20to%20decode%20your%20URL%3F%20Is%20it%20really%20to%20much%20effort%20to%20write%20a%20proper%20question%2C%20if%20you%20want%20people%20to%20spend%20there%20time%20to%20help%20you%3F

Comment: @Ridcully is that fine now?

Comment: The query is now readable. Can you reduce your code, so that you do just the actual query? Without the JSON stuff? Just to make sure, that it is really the query that takes so long. But it is quite clear that a 'like' search is taking some time. It seems you did apply fulltext index for the column. I'm not an expert for that, perhaps you find a tutorial or something on fulltext search with sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static JSONArray getResults(Database database, String query) {
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
        JSONArray resultSet = new JSONArray();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            int totalColumn = cursor.getColumnCount();
            JSONObject rowObject = new JSONObject();

            for (int i = 0; i < totalColumn; i++) {
                String columnName = cursor.getColumnName(i);
                if (columnName != null) {
                    try {
                        String columnValue = cursor.getString(i);
                        if (columnValue != null) {
                            if (isJSONValid(columnValue)) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(columnValue);
                                    rowObject.put(columnName, object);
                                }catch (JSONException e){
                                    Logger.error(e);
                                }
                            } else {
                                rowObject.put(columnName, columnValue);
                            }
                        } else {
                            rowObject.put(columnName, "");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Logger.error(e);
                    }
                }
            }
            resultSet.put(rowObject);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return resultSet;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, that did not help